# Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("289.......E6") to get test ads on this device

Tags: android, flutter, admob, firebase-admob

**Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("289.......E6") to get test ads on this device.**

I was getting this statement in the logcat terminal. When implementing the Google AdMob with the Test Ads provided in https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads#enable_test_devices in my Flutter App.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Solution

The way to solve it is to update `RequestConfiguration` with the **testDeviceIds**

```
String version;
  List<String> testDeviceIds = ['289C....E6'];

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  timeDilation = 1;
  PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  version = packageInfo.version;
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();

  // thing to add
  RequestConfiguration configuration =
       RequestConfiguration(testDeviceIds: testDeviceIds);
  MobileAds.instance.updateRequestConfiguration(configuration);


  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

### How to get TestDeviceIDs

If you want to test ads in your app as you're developing.

- Load your ads-integrated app and make an ad request.
- Check the logcat output for a message that looks like the one below, which shows you your device ID and how to add it as a test device:

`Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceIds(Arrays.asList("289.......E6") to get test ads on this device.`

- Add the device ID that your logcat gave you in the terminal, and use it as testDeviceId